LaTeX isn't working?
It seems like the LaTeX support hasn't been enabled yet.  
$\sum \limits_{i=1}^N x_i \hat \pi_i$

Thanks @Geoff Dalgas!

Great work, Geoff.

Checking for a code example in C++:
int main ()
{
    std::count << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Syntax highlighting is off, but the formatting came out.
